Read functions saves data into the database rather than reading it and loging me
I am fairly new to PHP and I'm doing a simple login and sign up form for a social website I am making. Im coding on VS studio code and using different files such as .html , .css and .php. Im still figuring out on how to link php and html together but I successfully got my sign up to work and it registers my data into my database (im using XAMPP). the problem occured when i was trying to login in.
my sign up and login form are on the same html file as im using some js to make it visible and hidden when the user either clicks on login or register.
 <form method="post" action="/Php/login.php">
      <!-- Input box for email for login panel  -->
      <div class="input_box">
        <span class="icon"><i class="bx bxs-envelope"></i></span>
        <input name="email" type="email" required placeholder="email" />
      </div>
      <!-- input box for password for login panel -->
      <div class="input_box">
        <span class="icon"><i class="bx bxs-lock-open"></i></span>
        <input
          name="password"
          type="password"
          required
          placeholder="Password?"
        />
      </div>

<?php

session_start();
include("/xampp/htdocs/FinalYearProject/Php/signup.php");
include("/xampp/htdocs/FinalYearProject/Php/connect.php");

class Login
{

    private $Error = "";


    public function CheckLogin($data)
    {

        $email = addslashes($data['email']);
        $password = addslashes($data['password']);


        //SQL QUERY to get email 
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email' limit 1";

        $DB = new ConnectDB();
        $result =  $DB->read($query);

        // password check and more security 
        if ($result) {
            $row = $result[0];
            if ($password == $row['password']) {
                //creating a session to maintain info for different pages/move info for the same website
                $_SESSION['gameimperiumUserID'] = $row['UserID'];
            } else {
                $this->Error .= "Invalid Password<br>";
            }
        } else {
            $this->Error .= "Invalid Email<br>";
        }

        return $this->Error;
    }
}



if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { // information contained by the server about the server

    $login = new Login();
    $result = $login->CheckLogin($_POST);

    if ($result != "") {

        echo "<div style = 'text-align: center; font-size: 12px ; color:white; background-color: grey;'>";
        echo "the follow errors occured<br>";
        echo $result;
        echo "</div>";
    } else {
        header("Location: http://localhost/Html/Profile.html");
        die;
    }
}

I have different files for signup and connect to DB. The main problem is when i enter data into the login form and submit it , the data goes into the database and makes a new entry for a new user.
I tried changing names and variables, getting everything under a single file and changing include files but none work. I want the php file to successfully read data from the database and redirect me to my header location and do this without making a new entry in the database for a new user

Creating a register/login system isn't all that easy, as you are discovering. It can however, be a good way to learn. One thing you really need to learn, from the start, is to use prepared SQL statements. Doing without is just not acceptable. The reason is that putting user input in database query strings is just asking for trouble. For an introduction into this problem see: SQL Injection. To read more about this, and what you can do about it see: Manual.

You currently send user input directly into a class method with $login->CheckLogin($_POST);. My advice is to sanitize user input as soon as possible and then name it in such a way you know it is user input. Something like: $userInputEmail = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "email", FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL); and $userInputPassword = $_POST["password"];, and then use these variables.

Sorry, I can't answer your actual question. The code that actually inserts data into the database is absent from your question. My guess is that you simply trigger the sign-up routine again when you log in.

If you really want to learn how to properly program in PHP you could try to post all of your code on Code Review. First make sure it actually works as intended. Use prepared statements. You can get a lot more very good, in-depth, advice there.
